# Symbols doesn't been uploaded to Crashlytics

Tags: crashlytics

I try to upload an iOS dSYM.zip file to crashytics manually through the web site.
After I choose file the site immediatly shows me warning "Zip up the dSYM folder and try again". Warning is showed so quickly that it is unpossible extracts archive or uploads its to the server. My file has a zip extensions and contains dSYM folder. What does it mean?[image]

UPD:
Zip contains two files:

- appname.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/appname
- appname.app.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here, it sounds like the zip contains more then just the dSYMs of your app. I'd remove anything that's not a dSYM and try to upload it.

Comment: Mike, I've updated my question. What do you think unnecessary?

Comment: Those should be fine. Can you email the dSYM zipped up to support(at)fabric(dot)io so we can take a deeper look? You can reference this post in your email and I'll make sure to find it.

Comment: I have sent it.